# Using 1 AutoPilot traversing series of siblings inside a series of siblings?

Tags: vtd-xml

I have an XML that looks like below. I want to traverse all the series of sibling using one shared AutoPilot. After selectXPath on /a/b which brings me on the first b sibling, I am trying to use same AutoPilot to selectXPath on c which will return all the c siblings. However, after the c traverse loop, I do not know how to bring back the context of the b traverse loop. The purpose intending to use one shared AutoPilot is to improve performance. Any thoughts?

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>c1</c>
        <d>d1.1</d>
        <d>d1.2</d>
        <d>d1.3</d>
        <d>d1.4</d>
        <d>d1.5</d>
        <d>d1.6</d>
        <e>e1</e>
    </b>
    <b>
        <c>c2</c>
        <d>d2.1</d>
        <d>d2.2</d>
        <d>d2.3</d>
        <e>e2</e>
    </b>
</a>
```

Having the XML above, my motivation is to get the values by traversing the hierarchy of the XML.  The requirement actually is to create a java object representation of the hierarchy. In order to achieve that I am doing a recursive approach using depth-first algorithm. Below is just to demonstrate my intent, I just to loops. As noticed, that in the inner loop, I am forced to create a new AutoPilot inside the loop to maintain the other context which is traversing the /a/b. Now, I would like to know how I can have one AutoPilot althrough out. I have tried he vtd.push and vtd.pop. It did not work.

```
VTDGen vtdGen = new VTDGen();
vtdGen.setDoc(this.xml.getBytes());
vtdGen.parse(false);
VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();

AutoPilot autoPilot1 = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot1.selectXPath("/a/b");
while (autoPilot1.evalXPath() != -1)
{
    AutoPilot autoPilot2 = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
    autoPilot2.selectXPath("c");
    System.out.println(autoPilot2.evalXPathToString());
    autoPilot2.selectXPath("d");
    while (autoPilot2.evalXPath() != -1)
    {
        System.out.println(vtdNav.toNormalizedXPathString(vtdNav.getCurrentIndex()));
    }
    autoPilot2.selectXPath("e");
    System.out.println(autoPilot2.evalXPathToString());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u post your code?

Comment: You need to take "c" and "d" out of the loop

Answer (score 0):

My fix of your code. let me know if there is any question. Notice that AutoPilot does not cache xpath expressions. One xpath corresponds to one AutoPilot object.

```
VTDGen vtdGen = new VTDGen();
vtdGen.setDoc(this.xml.getBytes());
vtdGen.parse(false);
VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();
AutoPilot autoPilot2 = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot2.selectXPath("c");
AutoPilot autoPilot3 = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot3.selectXPath("e");
AutoPilot autoPilot4 = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot4.selectXPath("d");
System.out.println(autoPilot2.evalXPathToString());
autoPilot1.selectXPath("/a/b");
while (autoPilot1.evalXPath() != -1)
{

    System.out.println(autoPilot2.evalXPathToString());
    vtdNav.push();
    while (autoPilot2.evalXPath() != -1)
       {     System.out.println(vtdNav.toNormalizedXPathString(vtdNav.getCurrentIndex()));
    }
    vtdNav.pop();
   System.out.println(autoPilot3.evalXPathToString());
   System.out.println(autoPilot4.evalXPathToString());
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to use one autopilot? This way I can improve performance by caching xpath.

Comment: using one autoPilot doesn't improve performance, you should/can instantiate as many autoPilots, as long as the substantiations are not done repetitively, there is no performance loss...

Comment: Subtantiation should have been instantiation..sorry for the typo

Comment: If I am processing multiple XML files, do I need to call selectXPath every XML processing?

Comment: if xpath does not change, u only compile it once and reuse as many times as you can...

Comment: thank you. it work smoothly. by reusing the AutoPilot, I was able to bring down the CPU usage from 60 to 5 percent. a 20MB file with 150 xpaths was processed in 0.7 seconds.